# Unity shader opengl или cg

Tags: unity3d, opengl, шейдеры, opengles

Только начал изучать, поставил перед собой задачу наложить на текстуру ещё текстуру(наложить как в фотошоп, на картинку наложить поверх другую картинку) только таким образом, чтобы она накладывалась не в середину(допустим объекта "plane") а именно в то место куда укажу координатами без растяжения. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: А что вы уже сделали или попробовали сделать?

Comment: в юнити для этого можно использовать projector

Comment: Повторил все примеры как на cg так и на glsl с сайта wikibooks. Покрутил параметры этих примеров в unity. Сейчас читаю книгу по gles 3.0. На английском рано мне, суть не улавливаю. С этого сайта более менее разобрался с языком shaderLab. Ответ, как смешать или наложить картинку с картинкой пока есть вариант просто смешать 2 картинки, причем таким образом, что на одной из картин будет картинка, за ранее размещенная в том месте, где задумано, а вокруг нее все остальное будет "залито" одинаковым цветом или прозрачным. Projector буду пробовать.